# Prove the inverse of a nonnegative matrix is nonnegative

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Defintion of a nonnegative matrix:

Symmetrical matrix $A: n \times n$ is non-negatively defined when $A > 0$ or $A ≥ 0$

We have to prove the following:
If $A$ is defined as a nonnegative matrix, there exists $A^{-1}$ only while $A>0$.

I don't understand how to prove this property. Why am I told $A$ has been defined as nonnegative and yet for an inverse to exist it has to be positive?

Comment: Do you mean negative definite matrix?

Answer (score 1):

because a symmetric, $A$, can be written as $U^{*}DU$. And we have known that there is no 0-entry in $D$, so we can get $A^{-1}$ = $U^{*}D^{-1}U $. Or you can just say that the $dim(null(D)) = 0$ $\implies$ $dim(null(A))= 0$ $\implies$ $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

*Non-negative definite* means that all its eigenvalues are greater than or equal to zero. *Positive definite* means that all its eigenvalues are greater than zero. Note that all positive definite matrices are also non-negative definite!

Think about what it means for a matrix to be invertible (in particular, how does its eigenvalues have to be) and you'll figure out why it has to be positive definite.

Comment: I understand that for a matrix to be invertible the number $0$ must not be an eigenvalue of $A$. However I do not understand how this helps me prove that an inverse matrix exists.